# os.walk() visits same folder twice

Tags: python, python-3.x, os.walk

I'm writing simple script using [mutagen library](https://mutagen.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which counts amount of audio files in folder and entire audio play time of folder (including audio files from subfolders).

```
import os,sys
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3
from mutagen.flac import FLAC
from mutagen.aac import AAC
from mutagen.aiff import AIFF
from mutagen.asf import ASF

audio_ext={"mp3":lambda x: MP3(x).info.length,
           "aac":lambda x: AAC(x).info.length,
           "wmv":lambda x: ASF(x).info.length,
           "wma":lambda x: ASF(x).info.length,
           "asf":lambda x: ASF(x).info.length,
           "flac":lambda x: FLAC(x).info.length,
           "aiff":lambda x: AIFF(x).info.length,}

def scan_lib(path):
    playtime = 0
    audio_files = 0
    for root,dirs,files in os.walk(path,followlinks=False):
        for f in files:
           try:
               playtime += audio_ext[f[len(f)-f[::-1].index('.'):]](os.path.join(root,f))
               audio_files += 1
           except (KeyError,ValueError):
               pass

        for d in dirs:
            dir_playtime,dir_audios = scan_lib(os.path.join(root,d))
            playtime +=dir_playtime
            audio_files += dir_audios

    print("\nLibrary:",path)
    print("Amount of audio files:",audio_files)
    print("Total playing time:\nDays\tHours\tMin\tSec\n%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\n" % convert_pt(playtime))
    return playtime,audio_files

def convert_pt(sec):
    t = datetime(1,1,1) + timedelta(seconds=int(sec))
    return t.day-1, t.hour,t.minute,t.second

main_path = sys.argv[1]
playtime,audio_files = scan_lib(main_path)
```

After some tests I figured out that my script visits some folders twice. Usually those directories are subfolders in another subfolders. As the result it prints this kind of result:

```
$ python3 music_scan.py 

Library: ~/Music/
Amount of audio files: 3520
Total playing time:
Days    Hours   Min Sec
9   7   30  26
```

But in reality if you move all audio tracks into one folder and run script on that test folder it shows different result:

```
$ python3 music_scan.py ~/test
Library: ~/test/
Amount of audio files: 885
Total playing time:
Days    Hours   Min Sec
2   15  49  9
```

Indeed amount of audio tracks in test folder was 885 . I checked it with `ls | wc -l` command
So why os.walk() visit some subfolders twice?

Comment: You have `for f in files` and then `for d in dirs`, which surely visits the same files. One of these loops is not needed.

Comment: Doesn't the documentation for os.walk() say that it will walk the directory tree?  So why are you doing "for d in dirs"?

Comment: Some folders contains files and folders which also contain files. As far as I know `files` doesn't contain files from subfolders, it only contains names of files in itself. So i need recursively visit subfolders too? Or I misunderstand something?

Comment: @xbound: os.walk() will walk every folder and subfolder.  It returns the subfolders in each folder in case you need to use them.  In your case, you don't.

Comment: @Mike Thanks. I guess in my case it will be better to use `os.listdir()` like it was suggested below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`os.walk` already recursively walks the entire directory tree.

You, however, recursively call your method `scan_lib`:

```
def scan_lib(path):
    ...
    for root,dirs,files in os.walk(path,followlinks=False):
        ...
        for d in dirs:
            dir_playtime,dir_audios = scan_lib(os.path.join(root,d))
            ...
```

Either use [`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/os.html#os.listdir) instead of `os.walk` and keep the recursive calls, or simply remove the 4 lines starting with `for d in dirs:`.